# Save a list of different sized matrices to a file

Tags: r, list, matrix, save

I'm trying to figure out how to best save a list of matrices. Each matrix is a different size (same number of columns, but the number of rows ranges from 300 to 1500). I did it that way instead of as an array to save memory, since I have over 30,000 matrices. I have tried saving it as a CSV, a txt, a data, and using the capture function, but it never seems to load back in correctly, usually with this sort of error "line 1 did not have 8 elements" or some variation of that. What's the best way to save a list with lots of large items of different size in a way that can be loaded back in? Thanks!

Comment: If all you care about is loading it back into R, then use `save` or `saveRDS`. If you need something compatible with other languages, and you must not save them in individual files, then perhaps a single JSON file of a list of matrices, see the `jsonlite` package.

Comment: I am currently using RDA files, which works, but then the file is over 6GB. I was hoping to find something that would be a little lighter on my processor because that's just the raw data I'm trying to analyze. I'll look into the jsonlite package!

Comment: You are not going to get much better than RDA, to be honest, not for speed, and you can do only slightly better for compression (*maybe*). 6GB seems like it might be a bit big, maybe not. Are you just doing `save(list_of_matrices, file="file.rda")` or `save(mtx1, mtx2, ..., file="file.rda")`, or are you doing it some other way?

Comment: I have the matrices stored in a list (lista <- list(c(mtx1, mtx2, mtex3, etc))). It makes it really easy to pull the matrices out of the list, but when I save it as any sort of non-R file, I get errors loading the list back in. I've never had this much trouble saving data before, but then again I rarely have used lists before

Comment: A list of matrices is a really good way to work with them, certainly. BTW, one thing seems odd: you said *matrix "instead of as an array"* suggesting that you originally have matrices of more than 2 dimensions, yet you intentionally split them into 2D matrices *"to save memory"*. That latter part *makes no sense*: storing numbers in a (not-small) 3D (or more) array is *always* more memory-efficient than a list of 2D matrices. I recognize you likely had arrays of different dims (based on *"300 to 1500"*), but it is usually better to keep them as a single multi-D array (depending on calcs).

Comment: Really? Did not know that. I can re-evaluate that bit. I think one of the reasons I ended up going with a list is so that I wouldn't have to create a process for storing them in a pre-fabricated array, especially since after extraction I need to run something that refuses to run if NAs are present, which is how I had been planning to fill up the empty spaces to make them all the same length. However, I think sheer computational space/power is the issue I'm up against now, so I may need to go back to that.

Comment: For size comparison, see: `m <- array(runif(100^3), dim=c(100,100,100)); object.size(m); object.size(asplit(m, 3))`, where the `asplit` command returns a 100-long list of 2d matrices, and `m` is the full 3d array. The difference is not gargantuan. Know that the size of an array in R is typically `sz` (the size of a double, for instance) times the `prod(dim(ary))` *plus some overhead*; which means that one 100x100x100 array has one overhead, but a 100-long list of 100x100 matrices has 100 overheads (plus a little more for the list).

Comment: That’s actually really good to know. The list I’m working with is over 30k matrices, so I’d imagine the difference becomes worthwhile somewhere in there.

Comment: It might. It's not a huge difference, but if your rationale for splitting it is *entirely* based on perceived memory efficiency, then you may choose to rethink that decision. When I was learning how to deal with array dims above 3, it was often simpler to subset it and work on just 2-3D at a time, so it's also a learning process.

Comment: Is RDS/RDA the best way to save arrays too? Or is there a better way for them?

Comment: `RDS`/`RDA` are generally the best way to save *just-about-anything* in R. The benefits are very much due to its serialization: R knows perfectly how it wants to transform its object into byte-order on disk, and when it reads the file it knows exactly how it will go back into an R object. For just about all other formats, it needs to spend a bit more time/effort *parsing* the file and making determinations on R-object-structure. The times I choose against `.rds` files are when I need network-availability and/or cross-language (e.g., python) availability, for which `.rds` will not work.